# Can you define instructions, after .hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript

I was reading some code for a challenge I'm working on, and going this.

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) { if (value === '') { delete collection[id][prop]; } else { if (prop !== 'tracks') { collection[id][prop] = value; } else { collection[id].hasOwnProperty('tracks') ? collection[id].tracks.push(value) : collection[id].tracks = [value]; } } return collection; }
```

What does . hasOwnProperty ('tracks') ?  do?  Why the question mark, and why the colon.  Does it set instructions based on Boolean value of hasOwnProperty?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Thanks, apparently the ternary operator is ahead of this lesson.